# Spring CSRF unrestricted RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, csrf

Small question regarding a SonarQube scan on a SpringBoot project please.

I have a very simple handler, super simple, as follow:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, path = "/my/api")
    public Mono<String> question() {
        return myService.dosomething();
    }
```

I have Spring Security in my class path, this project is a Spring WebFlux Application using 2.6.7 and Java 11.

Upon static analysis scan, I am being flagged with:

**Spring CSRF unrestricted RequestMapping**

```
Description

<p>Methods annotated with <code>RequestMapping</code> are by default mapped to all the HTTP request methods.
However, Spring Security's CSRF protection is not enabled by default
for the HTTP request methods <code>GET</code>, <code>HEAD</code>, <code>TRACE</code>, and <code>OPTIONS</code>(as this could cause the tokens to be leaked).
Therefore, state-changing methods annotated with <code>RequestMapping</code> and not narrowing the mapping
to the HTTP request methods <code>POST</code>, <code>PUT</code>, <code>DELETE</code>, or <code>PATCH</code>are vulnerable to CSRF attacks.</p><p> <b>Vulnerable Code:</b><br/><pre><code>@Controller
public class UnsafeController {
...
<b>References</b><br/><a href="https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-use-proper-verbs">Spring Security Official Documentation: Use proper HTTP verbs (CSRF protection)</a><br/><a href="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29">OWASP: Cross-Site Request Forgery</a><br/><a href="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet">OWASP: CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet</a><br/><a href="https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/352.html">CWE-352: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)</a></p>
```

I do not understand this issue.

What I tried:

I tried splitting the Controller onto two different controllers, one for each verb, and for some reason, this fix the issue:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(path = "/my/api")
    public Mono<String> questionGet() {
        return myService.dosomething();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(path = "/my/api")
    public Mono<String> questionPost() {
        return myService.dosomething();
    }
```

But I am now carrying a duplicate, therefore, I would like to stay with my:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}
```

I also added Spring Security to protect myself against CSRF, but no luck, the issue still persist.

May I ask what is the proper way to fix this please?

Thank you